# how to read a class object form file (using CFile) in mfc?

Tags: mfc

class CMyFile
{
    int a;
    wchar_t str[10];
public:
    CMyFile()
    {
        a = 12;
        wcscpy(str, L"ddddd");
    }
};

i am writing in following way
CMyFile l_temp;

```
CFile myFile;
CFileException fileException;

if ( !myFile.Open( pszFileName, CFile::modeCreate |   
    CFile::modeReadWrite, &fileException ) )
{
    TRACE( L"Can't open file %s, error = %u\n",
        pszFileName, fileException.m_cause );
}
else
{
    myFile.Write((wchar_t*)&l_temp,sizeof(CMyFile));
    myFile.Close();
    }
```

but when i reading it is not reading correc t values
reading code is given below
class CMyFile
{
    int a;
    //abc obj;
    wchar_t str[10];
public:
    CMyFile()
    {
        //a = 12;
        //wcscpy(str, L"ddddd");
    }
};

CMyFile l_temp;

```
CFile myFile;
CFileException fileException;

if ( !myFile.Open( pszFileName, CFile::modeCreate |   
    CFile::modeReadWrite, &fileException ) )
{
    TRACE( L"Can't open file %s, error = %u\n",
        pszFileName, fileException.m_cause );
}
else
{

    myFile.Read((wchar_t*)&l_temp,sizeof(CMyFile));//not reading correctly
    myFile.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use MFC  [serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/serialization_primer1.aspx?msg=406879)